# Voiced aspirated alveolar trill

Tags: phonetics, greek, history, ancient, aspiration

Was there voiced aspirated alveolar trill in Ancient Greek? It was written in some sites in Russian that all Ancient Greek words which began with "rho" pronounced with the sound [rʰ], but it was written in English Wikipedia that such words pronounced with the voiceless alveolar trill. 
In addition, can you send the example of the sound [rʰ], please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no phonetic difference between voiceless aspirated vs. unaspirated trill, and phonologically speaking, voiceless trills (and other sonorants) behave like they are aspirates. The distinction between trill and tap has to do with the number of hits. It is likely that Ancient Greek initial *r* (ῥ) was not a fricative and was voiceless, but it would take impossible-to-obtain phonetic data from a speaker to make any more specific claim about the phonetics of that sound. Recordings of Ancient Greek are, needless to say, not derived from native speakers. You can listen to initial "hr" in Icelandic on Forvo. The speakers who recorded [hrista](https://forvo.com/word/hrista/#is) "shake" differ, where "bjarkibjarki" produces a credible voiceless trill, likewise his rendition of [hrist](https://forvo.com/word/hrist/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what about Urdu? What is the nature of the voiced aspirated [r] in this language? Is it as the same as in Icelandic or not? Can I find the pronunciation of Urdu word with the sound?